# Making lists that are easier to edit

Tags: list

How can I change the interface of my lists? I have to edit many of them, and the way I am doing it now is quite tedious:

1. Click an item to enter a separate page about that item
2. Change the elements I need modified
3. Return to list and click the next item I need changed

This is extremely slow. Is it possible to change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or Open the list in Datasheet view from the ribbon and then edit the fields of the item one by one on the same page.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Quick Edit function in the ribbon. This will allow you to edit in a spreadsheet-like mode. Note that this control is disabled when using certain types of views of a list, e.g. when Grouping is enabled.